# How to integrate/link the .bas vba module file contents (variables) into the vba project?

Tags: vba, ms-word

We have 2 macros - say M1 and M2.

The M1 macro is working correctly.

The M2 macro is not working as expected (there are no compile/run-time errors) and the reason for this is that 1 file is missing in this macro M2. Say F1.bas. This file has the foll. code:

```
Public Const REG_SZ As Long = 1
```

The other files in the macro refer to this REG_SZ. On Macro M1 if I right click on the REG_SZ in the other files and click on Definition, then it takes me to the F1.bas file on this line.

However, on the M2 although I have imported the F1.bas file, and compiled the code; If I right click on the REG_SZ in the other files and click on Definition, then it gives an popup that says: "Identifier under cursor is not recognized".

My understanding is that any public variable in the module file should be globally accessible. Is there something that I am missing to establish the link, do we need to do something else when importing a module file?

Comment: Some minimal reproducible code would be good in order to understand your problem? Why do you need the .bas file? Did you maybe do a syntax error?

Comment: No syntax error. Compiles OK. .bas file is needed because it has lot of more global variables. Its just basic code, it looks like the link is missing as explained in the question. I know that in some frameworks you need to include the other files, but in VBA my understanding is that anything declared as Public is global and available in any module file.

Comment: try something like: F1.REG_SZ instead of just REG_SZ

Comment: Yes, that works, but it will mean a lot of changes (find/replace) in the code which is not what I am looking; because the same concept works in the M1 macro by directly referring to REG_SZ, instead of F1.REG_SZ. ANy other suggestions please.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda. Hello, I notice that once I add the F1.REG_SZ it works and also then when I remove that "F1." keyword and just keep "REG_SZ" then it continues working only for that line. The other REG_SZ still dont work. So is there some other way to link them all please?

Comment: Every .bas should start with `OPTION EXPLICIT`. That will avoid you some situations where a module compiles but gives a runtime error.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to identify such broken links (in my case there was no compile/run-time error)?

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429300/how-to-identify-broken-vba-code-in-absence-of-compile-run-time-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May i suggest that instead of importing F1.bas, create a new module next to M1/M2 and copy contents of F1.

I was able to reproduce your problem, and copying the contents instead of just importing seems to be processed differently by the editor. As for the reasons why... I can't help.

Further testing shows that commenting your variable `Public Const REG_SZ As Long = 1` and uncommenting it, forces the editor to recognise it again (from the imported file).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to identify such broken links (in my case there was no compile/run-time error)?

Comment: Could make a sub to debug.print each variable... can't think of a better way. `Sub test()

If REG_SZ <> 1 Then Debug.Print "REG_SZ link missing."

End Sub
`

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429300/how-to-identify-broken-vba-code-in-absence-of-compile-run-time-errors

Comment: I always use Option Explicit at the top for my code, though not for quick testing like for your case... so yeah, that's another way, but it will pretty much stop you at one variable at the time... not particularly useful in your case, depending how often you need to import your modules.