# How to identify broken vba code in absence of compile/run-time errors?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to know if there is any way to identify all the broken vba code (example: variables) in absence of compile/run-time errors?

For example:

Let's say there is a variable defined in ModuleA.bas as:

`Public Const REG_SZ AS Long = 1`

Other files, say ModuleB.bas, ModuleC.bas, etc make use of this variable.

Now, if we delete the ModuleA.bas file that contains the variable REG_SZ, and build the project, then we see no compile or run-time errors. **Only while debugging you realize that the program defaults this variable to be having no value. When you right click this variable in the other modules and click on 'Definiton' you get an error that says: "Identifier under cursor is not recognized".** The solution is to declare this variable locally on each file, or re-instate the original ModuleA.bas file with that variable declared.

I would like to know if there is any way to identify all the broken vba code (example: variables) in absence of compile/run-time errors?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) add-in. It will inspect your code for common problems (including undeclared variables).  Full disclosure, I am a contributor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question on variables ... Put an `Option Explicit` statement at the top of each code module. Any VBA code you insert that does not declare its variables will automatically be flagged without having to compile the the code.

Comment: Do you mean it will force variable declaration on that file itself? Or is it OK as long as a variable is available somewhere in the project.?

Comment: @variable It's specific to the code module. If you have multiple modules, each must have an Option Explicit. Each UserForm would also need the statement.

Comment: @variable it depends wheter it's a public or private variable. Try searching/reading about it because it's a bit complex.

Comment: Any article links or search keywords on this concept will be appreciated please. thank you.

Comment: @variable try searching: word vba define variable

Comment: @variable There also is a setting in the VBE's options menu: `Require variable declaration` (or similar) - this will automatically add `Option Explicit` to any new module created from that point on. (I highly recommend activating that setting!)

Answer (score 2):

There's a setting in the [Editor] tab of the VBE options dialog labelled "Require Variable Declaration", that will automatically add `Option Explicit` to every module:

[image: require variable declaration]

Having `Option Explicit` in a module's *declarations* section makes VBA refuse to compile/run a project that uses undeclared variables.

The Visual Basic Editor (VBE) will not help much beyond that, however VBE add-ins, such as [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck), can push static code analysis much further - for example it can warn you when `Option Explicit` is missing from a module, if a variable is never assigned or if a procedure isn't used, if an assignment is redundant or overwritten before its value is used, if the `IsMissing` function is misused, ...and so many others (approximately 80 inspections are implemented as of v2.3, scheduled to release November 25):

[image: Rubberduck code inspections toolwindow]

Disclaimer: I manage this open-source project.